# Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1707 (also 1709)

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I created an MSI installer with WiX 3.8 and I get this error at the very end of the MSI log when installing it:

```
[...]
Property(C): WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID = 1
=== Logging stopped: 8/20/2014  19:15:03 ===
Note: 1: 1707 
Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1707 
Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
Product: CmisSync Shell Extension -- Installation completed successfully.

Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: My Shell Extension. Product Version: 0.2.23. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Me. Installation success or error status: 0.

Grabbed execution mutex.
Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MainEngineThread is returning 0
=== Verbose logging stopped: 8/20/2014  19:15:03 ===
```

How can I fix these errors?
Or maybe they are known WiX/MSI issues that can be safely ignored?

My WiX script is extremely simple, it just installs a shell extension, so I have no idea where this error comes from.

From the GUI point of view, the installation finishes with no visible problem. All files are present as expected in the target installation folder.

Answer (score 7):

That is MSI trying to find resources in the Error table but you probably don't have an Error table in your MSI.  Here is a list of the message strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835(v=vs.85).aspx.  As you can see 1707 & 1709 are the ids for the success messages you see following these messages.

Answer (score 4):

For fix such errors in the log files, you need to add reference to the definition of "Error" table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Fragment>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Except 'Fragment', you also can put this reference into the 'Module', 'PatchFamily', 'Product', 'UI'.

Reference to original answer which helped me:
http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Error-Table-td694988.html

Comment: Thanks that looks promising! But [my WXS file](https://github.com/aegif/CmisSync/blob/master/CmisSync/Windows/Installer/Product.wxs) does not have any `<Fragment>` element... so where/how can I add this `WixUI_ErrorProgressText`?

Comment: Except 'Fragment', you also can put this reference into the 'Module', 'PatchFamily', 'Product', 'UI'. Please, have a look in the 
[WiX manual](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/uiref.html)

Comment: FYI, this doesn't seem to work with WiX 4 projects neither in a Product or Fragment section: `The identifier 'WixUI:WixUI_ErrorProgressText' could not be found. Ensure you have typed the reference correctly and that all the necessary inputs are provided to the linker.
`

Answer (score 0):

These are just verbose/debug messages (It looks that you start your installation in verbose mode, right?). I wouldn't assume these are real errors. If I start my msi installation in verbose mode, I am getting similar 'errors'.