# InstallShield - how to write custom action functions

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installshield, setup-project, custom-action

I am trying to create installer using InstallShield and have requirement to execute some code during the installation process. Earlier I was using VS 2015 setup extension to create MSI but due to some advance needs in MSI we are planning to migrated to InstallShield and code that we were executing in **onBeforeInstall / onAfterInstall of ServiceInstall** also needs to be executed and as per my understanding we need to create CustomActions and for that requirement is to create functions and put them in dll file.

I tried to look into documents of InstallShield but wasn't able to find good way or example code that i can start with to write such code. I prefer to write in C# it will be helpful if some one can guide me to write function to attach with custom actions.

Answer (score 0):

***Help Material***: [The documentation included with InstallShield](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm) should have good information to get going? [Installscript Reference](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefHome.htm). Also check the Installshield installation folder under Program Files - I think there are some samples there.

[***Installsite.org***](http://www.installsite.org): Setup consultant Stefan Kruger's [installsite.org](http://www.installsite.org) has a number of coding examples for custom actions.

[***Github.com***](https://www.github.com): You can search [github.com](https://www.github.com) to find samples of just about anything. [Sample search for MsiGetProperty](https://github.com/search?q=MsiGetProperty&type=Code) (used by most Installscripts).

***Custom Actions***: Managed code (Dot Net) has a number of technical problems for large scale package distribution. It is recommended that you use Installshield's proprietary **Installscript** language or straight up **C++** (minimal dependency, static linking when possible). I don't have a nice summary of managed code problems, only [this half-mad answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48465731/129130) that was written some time ago.