# msi installer using WIX: Error 2228 on closing

Tags: xml, error-handling, dialog, wix, windows-installer

I'm creating a .msi installer using WIX and when I close the dialog I get the following message (see image):

[Pop up - Error 2228](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUtK8.png)

Here it is the code:

```
  <UI>
     <Dialog Id="ExitDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="MiTek Revit Plugins Setup">
        <Control Id="Finish" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Cancel="yes" Text="Finish" />
        <!--<Control Id="Finish" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="Finish" />-->
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="135" Y="70" Width="220" Height="40" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Installation Successful." />
     </Dialog>

     <InstallUISequence>
        <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success" />
     </InstallUISequence>

     <AdminUISequence>
        <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success" />
     </AdminUISequence>
  </UI>
```

The installation is successful and it does not break anything, but still I would like to get rid of it. Any hint?

Comment: You can see this answer on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045359/windows-installer-fails-on-win-10-but-not-win-7-using-wix/46058543. If it helps.

Comment: @BadhanSen not exactly the same error. There the 2228 looks like some line of the msi installer, but the error is a 1603.
I've only found [this](https://www.itninja.com/question/help-with-msi-2228) so far, but still haven't found the soultion.